# Rails application on Cent OS azure virtual machine not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, centos, putty

I have created one Cent Os Virtual Machine on windows Azure for deploying my rails application. I am using the following steps for accessing my app..

```
1.Doing SSH to my app xxx.cloudapp.net
2.Giving rails s command in my app directory.
```

I am able to view my app running on azure cloud. But the problem is server gets stopped for every 10-15 minutes and again I need to restart my server with rails s

Am I following the correct procedure or is there any other method to keep the server continuously running?